# custom field as a boolean with a checkbox?

Tags: custom-field

I have installed the more fields plugin which gives me access to a custom field checkbox.  When setting the field up through the plugin the caption says: Creates single checkbox, which key is either on/off.  As you can see by the query I am looking for all the events whose event-archive = on.

Is there a better way to do this?  This doesn't return any posts anyways. Is there a better way to build a boolean field?

```
$archive_query = new WP_Query(
        array( 
          'post_type'  => 'event',        // only query events
          'meta_key'    => 'event-archive',  // load up the event_date meta
          'order'       => 'desc',         // ascending, so earlier events first
          'posts_per_page' => '5',
          'meta_query'  => array(
             array(         // restrict posts based on meta values
              'key'     => 'event-archive',  // which meta to query
              'value'   => 'on',  // value for comparison
              'compare' => '=',          // method of comparison
              'type'    => 'CHAR'         // datatype, we don't want to compare the string values
             ) // meta_query is an array of query ites
            ) // end meta_query array
          ) // end array
        ); // close WP_Query constructor call
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you already looked at the output of WP_Query, if you don't submit the "meta_query" key? Do you get the posts for the event-posttype?

If yes, then you could check what the "more fileds"-plugin puts in the "event-archive" custom field. Maybe you have to set the value to integer 1 or just submit a boolean true. e.g.

```
array(
'key'     => 'event-archive', 
'value'   => 1
)

array(
'key'     => 'event-archive', 
'value'   => true
)
```

**EDIT**

I've just installed the plugin, created a new meta field "event-archive" of type "checkbox" and some posts with and without this meta value.

If I use the following query, I get all posts from posttype "event" with the metavalue selected.

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'event',
'order' => 'desc',
'posts_per_page' => '5',
'numberposts' => -1,
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'event-archive',
        'value' => 1,
        'compare' => '=',
        'type' => 'CHAR'
    )
)

$archive_posts = get_posts($args);
print_r($archive_posts);
```

**Note**

- You can also use WP_Query if you like
- The "meta_query" parameter requires WordPress 3.1

Comment: I can get the events post type if I remove the meta_query.  The More-Fields plugin checkbox is returning a 1.  But if I do key => event-archive, value => '1', and compare => =, and type = numberic, it does not return any events.  Even though I have an event with the box checked.

Comment: I've editied my last post. On my site, this is working as expected.